# Check if column has same value for a client group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like the below and want to identify duplicate referrals

```
Client      Team                Referred Date

client1     Referred Team1      2016-02-16
client1     Referred Team1      2016-02-16
client1     Referred Team1      2016-02-16
client1     Referred Team1      2016-01-28
Client2     Referred Team4      2015-07-03
Client2     Referred Team4      2015-07-03
Client3     Referred Team7      2015-04-09
Client3     Referred Team7      2015-04-09
Client3     Referred Team7      2015-04-09
Client3     Referred Team2      2016-09-28
Client3     Referred Team1      2016-10-20
Client4     Referred Team8      2016-11-18
```

My query so far below, but i dont seem to get the desired result

```
SELECT 
ClientId
,Team
,COUNT(*) as DuplicateCount

FROM MyData
group by 
ClientId
,Team
having COUNT(*) >1
```

I would like  the below result

```
Client      Team                Duplicate Count (Times referred to the same team)

client1     Referred Team1      4
Client2     Referred Team4      2
Client3     Referred Team7      3
Client4     Referred Team8      1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: If a client is referred to multiple teams do you want to see them all in the results?

Comment: Also in your desired results you have Client4 with a Duplicate Count of 1. That isn't a duplicate, are you sure you want that?

Comment: I dont want to see if the client is referred multiple teams, but would like to see if they are referred more than once to a same team. yes, you could ignore client 4 with. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use row_number and subquery as below

```
 Select top (1) with ties * from (
     Select Client, Team , Cnt = Count(ReferredDate)
         from yourtable 
         group by Client, Team ) a
     order by row_number() over(partition by Client order by cnt desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want the team with the most rows for each client.  This is called the *mode* in statistics:

```
SELECT ct.*
FROM (SELECT ClientId, Team, COUNT(*) as DuplicateCount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MyData
      GROUP BY ClientId, Team
     ) ct
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

You can filter out the non-duplicates with a `HAVING` or `WHERE` clause.

EDIT:

A slight variation of Kannan's answer removes the need for a subquery:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES ClientId, Team, COUNT(*) as DuplicateCount
FROM MyData
GROUP BY ClientId, Team
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;With cte(Client,Team ,ReferredDate)
AS
(
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1','2016-02-16' Union all
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1','2016-02-16' Union all
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1','2016-02-16' Union all
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1','2016-01-28' Union all
SELECT 'Client2','Referred Team4','2015-07-03' Union all
SELECT 'Client2','Referred Team4','2015-07-03' Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team7','2015-04-09' Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team7','2015-04-09' Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team7','2015-04-09' Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team2','2016-09-28' Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team1','2016-10-20' Union all
SELECT 'Client4','Referred Team8','2016-11-18' 
)
SELECT Client
    ,Team
    ,DupilcateTeamCount
FROM (
    SELECT Client
        ,Team
        ,DupilcateTeamCount
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Client ) AS Seq
    FROM (
        SELECT Client
            ,Team
            ,DupilcateTeamCount
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY Client) CCount
        FROM (
            SELECT *,COunt(Team) OVER (PARTITION BY Client,Team ORDER BY Team) AS DupilcateTeamCount
            FROM cte
            ) Dt
        ) DT2
    WHERE DT2.CCount = 1
    ) final
WHERE final.Seq = 1
```

OutPut

```
Client  Team            DupilcateTeamCount
----------------------------------------
Client1 Referred Team1       4
Client2 Referred Team4       2
Client3 Referred Team7       3
Client4 Referred Team8       1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing what you need is to count the distinct referred date for each client/team pair as duplicates. which could be traced by row_number() function.

See if below query works:

```
drop table test purge;
create table test (Client Varchar2(20), 
                       Team   Varchar2(20), 
                       ReferredDate Date);

insert into test 
select * from (

SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1',to_date('2016-02-16','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1',to_date('2016-02-16','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1',to_date('2016-02-16','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client1','Referred Team1',to_date('2016-01-28','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client2','Referred Team4',to_date('2015-07-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client2','Referred Team4',to_date('2015-07-03','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team7',to_date('2015-04-09','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team7',to_date('2015-04-09','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team7',to_date('2015-04-09','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team2',to_date('2016-09-28','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client3','Referred Team1',to_date('2016-10-20','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual Union all
SELECT 'Client4','Referred Team8',to_date('2016-11-18','YYYY-MM-DD') from dual

);

commit;

---=========================================================================================
with t1 as (
select client, team, referreddate, row_number() over (partition by client, team order by referreddate) as dup_cnt
from test 
     )
select distinct client, team, max(dup_cnt)
from t1
group by client, team
order by 1,2
;
```

The output should be :

```
CLIENT  TEAM    MAX(DUP_CNT)
1   Client1 Referred Team1  4
2   Client2 Referred Team4  2
3   Client3 Referred Team1  1
4   Client3 Referred Team2  1
5   Client3 Referred Team7  3
6   Client4 Referred Team8  1
```